# How to include Bootstrap Icon to Button

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, bootstrap-5

I'm making a `button` using `createElement` in javascript.
I want to add a bootstrap delete icon in that `button`.

My code -

```
const aLink = document.createElement('button');
aLink.innerHTML = '<i class="bi bi-trash"></i> Delete'
document.body.append(aLink);
```

In chrome only a button appears with Delete written inside it. I've already included bootstrap stylesheet and script files in my HTML.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the link of the icons.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

In more general terms, if you want to see only the icon with the functionality of a button, this would be a clean solution:

```
<button type="button" class="btn">
 <img
  src="../assets/svgs/trash.svg"
  alt="delete icon"
  title="delete"
  />
</button>
```

Obviously adapt the `src`.